# Strange files ntd1l.dll and kern3l32.dll?

Tags: windows, malware

on my windows 7 PC i have an EXE file that sometimes crashes.
out of curiosity i took a look at the minidump file created by windows.

i have noticed two suspicious files that got loaded into the process:

- ntd1l.dll
- kern3l32.dll

[image: modules]

searching the web led me to one single [twitter post](https://twitter.com/gerritzc/status/925743243433791488?lang=en) where the author states that it was caused by some security software called `SentinelOne` and there was nothing to worry about.

however, i still have a bad feeling.
in particular as i can't find any official documentation of such behaviour.

those 2 files do *not* exist in my SysWOW64 folder.
but they are showing up in the minidump file ...
any advice how to further investigate this strange symptom?

Comment: I assume you actually have this security software installed on your system?  You have confirmed that these files actually exist in your SysWOW64 folder?

Comment: It is difficult to say if the files are legitimate honestly.  I personally, would uninstall SentinelOne, delete the files because they are not system files, then reinstall SentinelOne.  If you want an actual answer, update your question, with enough information determine if the files were installed by SentinelOne.  Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Just a small nitpick -- in the post you link to, the (apparently official) SentinelOne account [confirms these are part of its product](https://twitter.com/SentinelOne/status/925751088774463488).